# Number of elements of order $11$ in any group of order $198$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

This question was asked in my abstract algebra assignment which could not be discussed due to pandemic.

> Question: Show that in all groups of order $198$ number of elements of order $11$ are same.

Attempt: I thought using Sylow theorems that there exists a unique Sylow subgroup of order $11$. So, the elements of order $11$ is fixed which is $10$.

Is this reasoning correct? If not kindly tell me the right reasoning.

Comment: Could you be more precise about "there is a unique Sylow subgroup of order 11"? How did you go from "the number of Sylow 11-subgroups is conjugate to 1 (mod 11)" to "there is just one Sylow 11-subgroup"? I think that might have been the point of the assignment.

Comment: @Patrick Stevens The number $n_{11}$ also divides $18$, so it easily follows that it must be $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P\leq G$ be the unique $11$-Sylow subgroup. Every non identity element in $P$ must have order $11$ by Lagrange's theorem, so there are $10$ such elements in $P$. But we also have to prove that these are **all** the elements of order $11$ in $G$.

So suppose $g\in G$ has order $11$. Then $\langle g\rangle\leq G$ is a subgroup of order $11$. Since $|G|=2\times 3^2\times 11$ it follows that $\langle g\rangle$ is an $11$-Sylow subgroup of $G$. Since there is only one such subgroup we get $\langle g\rangle=P$, and thus $g\in P$. So indeed there can't be any other elements of order $11$.

Comment: This answer is correct, but in general any element of order $p$ is included in a $p$-Sylow subgroup, so the second part isn't really necessary.

Comment: @Sebastian Spindler You are right, but the general case is not very trivial. So I decided to simply write a proof for this easy case.

Comment: That's true, but this is usually either part of the definition of $p$-Sylow subgroups (if they are defined as maximal $p$-subgroups) or part of the Sylow theorems (if they are defined as subgroups of order $p^n$ with $p^n \mid |G|$, $p^{n+1} \nmid |G|$), which the OP seems to know.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a group of order $198 = 2\cdot 3^2 \cdot 11$. Let $n_{11}$ be the number of Sylow $11$-subgroups of $G$. $n_{11} \equiv 1 \mod 11$ so $n_{11}=1$ or $11$ and $n_{11} \mid 2\cdot 3^2$, which means $n_{11} = 1$ so there are exactly ten elements of order $11$ in $G$ (we're excluding the identity, which leaves us with $10=11-1$ eleemnts).